# Why is my loop taking forever to complete?

Tags: r, performance, loops, vectorization

I am running an algorithm to generate normal distribution from 2 exponentials as follows:

```
set.seed(69420)
j = 1 
Z = c()

# Algorithm
while(j <= 10000){ Y1 <- rexp(1); Y2 <- rexp(1)
    if(Y2 - (Y1 -1)^2/2 >= 0 ){
            X = Y1
            U <- runif(1,0,1)
            if(U > 0.5){
                    Z[j] = X
            } else {
                    Z[j] = -X
            }
            j = j+1
    }
}
```

Then I am asked to modify the code as follows: "When we accept the sample Y1 (as X = Y1), the random variable Y = Y2 - (Y1 -1)2 / 2 also follows an exponential distribution with rate 1, and it is independent of Y1. Modify your code to recycle Y as one of the samples required."

I have written the following code to do the above task.

```
set.seed(69420)
j = 1
Z = c()
count = 0
Y2 <- rexp(1)
#Algorithm
while(j <= 50){
    Y1 <- rexp(1)
    Y = Y2 - (Y1 -1)^2/2
    if(Y >= 0){
        X = Y1
        Y2 = Y
        U <- runif(1,0,1)
        if(U > 0.5){
            Z[j] = X
        }else {
            Z[j] = -X
        }
        j = j+1
    }
    else if(Y < 0 & j == 1){
       Y2 <- rexp(1)
    }
}
```

However, my loop keeps running forever and even to produce 50 iterations it takes 5 mins. Is there anything I am doing wrong that is causing a long-running time? Also, can anyone suggest a method to vectorize the above code so my processing time can be reduced? Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Posting the whole question below for a better explanation.

Using the rejection method, we can generate samples from a standard Gaussian
distribution N(0,1) using samples from an exponential distribution, Exp(1). The
algorithm is as follows:

1. Generate Y1, Y2, independent samples from Exp(1).
2. If Y2 - (Y1 -1)^2 / 2 >= 0, set X = Y1. Otherwise, go back to step 1.
3. Generate a sample U from a uniform U(0,1). If U > 0.5, set Z = X.
   Otherwise, set Z = -X.
   The variable Z follows a Gaussian distribution.

a) Implement the algorithm in R. Provide your code in a separate file, rejection.R.

b) Generate 10000 samples of a Gaussian distribution using your code and report the sample mean and standard deviation.

c) Modify your code to count how many samples of the exponential and uniform
distribution you need in order to obtain 10000 samples of a standard Gaussian. Run the code 10 times and report the average number of samples required.

d) When we accept the sample Y1 in step 2, the random variable Y = Y2 - (Y1 -1)2 / 2 also follows an exponential distribution with rate 1, and it is independent of Y1. Modify your code to recycle Y as one of the samples required in step 1. Submit your code in a separate file, rejection2.R.

e) Count how many samples is your code using now. Run the code 10 times and
report the average number of samples required.

Comment: Add some `print` statements inside to debug the issue

Comment: your j = j+1 is inside the if, so when your code goes to the else part or doesn't go inside the if, j doesn't increment.

Comment: also, growing vectors is very inefficient - try starting with `Z <- numeric(10000)` instead of `Z <- c()` (although the logic problem pointed out by @AdroMine is much more important). @AdroMine, post as an answer?

Comment: @BenBolker that isn't really the problem. The loop does complete, it just takes exponentially longer to increment j each time, waiting for the RNG to sample a smaller and smaller number. In the end, it gives the wrong result anyway - the algorithm just isn't right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're being confused by the wording. The point is simply that you should harvest `Y` in the loop for each iteration, and it should be an exponentially distributed variable with mean of approximately 1:

```r
set.seed(69420)
j = 1 
Z = c()
Y = c()

# Algorithm
while(j <= 10000){ Y1 <- rexp(1); Y2 <- rexp(1)
    if(Y2 - (Y1 -1)^2/2 >= 0 ){
            X = Y1
            Y[j] <- Y2 - (Y1 -1)^2 / 2
            U <- runif(1,0,1)
            if(U > 0.5){
                    Z[j] = X
            } else {
                    Z[j] = -X
            }
            j = j+1
    }
}
```

So Z should have a normal distribution:

```r
hist(Z)
```

[image]

and Y an exponential distribution

```r
hist(Y)
```

[image]

and the mean of Y should be close to 1:

```r
mean(Y)
#> [1] 0.9870445
```

---

**Edit**

With further information from OP, the correct algorithm is simply to sample Y2 from an exponential distribution if `Y` is rejected:

```r
set.seed(69420)
j = 1
Z = c()
count = 0
Y2 <- rexp(1)
#Algorithm
while(j <= 10000){
    Y1 <- rexp(1)
    Y = Y2 - (Y1 -1)^2/2
    if(Y >= 0){
        X = Y1
        Y2 = Y
        U <- runif(1,0,1)
        if(U > 0.5){
            Z[j] = X
        }else {
            Z[j] = -X
        }
        j = j+1
    }
    else {
       Y2 <- rexp(1)
    }
}

mean(Z)
#> [1] -0.00591165

sd(Z)
#> [1] 0.9961794
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I think I created confusion by posting an excerpt from the question asked as I don't want my assignment solved but just some help with the part I am getting stuck with. I am putting the whole question in the original text so that my problem can be better explained.

Comment: @KhurramAhmed ah, I see now. You were really close - just change your `ifelse` to an `else` - you need to resample Y2 in all cases where Y is rejected, not just when `j == 1`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I understand what my error was. I was looking for the Y1 values that would give a positive Y, but as my Y2 stayed constant, this forced the loop to find a smaller and smaller number through randomness. This I think is the reason why the processing time is increasing exponentially.